# Do something periodically while waiting for result of an GetAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, getasync

I want to start an `GetAsync` or `PostAsync` and then in a loop do something and check for results.

```
req1 = client.GetAsync(url_1); // a time consuming request

do
{
    //do something here
    var req2= await client.GetAsync(url_2);
    var result2 = await req2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
} while (!IsResultReady(req1)); // check if url_1 job is done and stop the loop

var result1 = await req1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: You seem to be just ignoring result2. I think the code might have lost some meaning. If i follow what you intend then you could put the req2 stuff in s separate thread starter tyat and just await the req1. Stop the req2 thread using a cancellation token after the await, when req1 returns it's result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this example should give you what you need

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var mainTask = MyLongRunningTask();
    // mainTask is already started without await
    do
    {
        await DoSomethingElse();
    } while (!mainTask.IsCompleted);
}

public async Task MyLongRunningTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Long Running Task Started");
    
    await Task.Delay(3000); // simulating client.GetAsync(url_1)
    
    Console.WriteLine("Long Running Task Finished");
}

async Task DoSomethingElse()
{
    Console.WriteLine("doing some other tasks");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

output:

```
Long Running Task Started
doing some other tasks
doing some other tasks
doing some other tasks
Long Running Task Finished
```